# curl -X POST (php)

Tags: php

I have the following Curl command. How do I execute this in PHP?

```
curl -X POST "https://api.mystream.to/v1/remote-upload"
  -H "Authorization: ACCESS_TOKEN"
  -d "url=<URL>&path=<PATH?>"
```

Comment: Check the following website, it will convert that code for you. https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mystream.to/v1/remote-upload');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "url=<URL>&path=<PATH?>");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: ACCESS_TOKEN';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

So I used the following website to generate this: [curl-to-PHP](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/)

Now if you want more of an explanation, here it goes.

---

1. Setting the URL

   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mystream.to/v1/remote-upload');`
2. Setting the body to what you had before

   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "url=<URL>&path=<PATH?>");`
3. Setting the Headers, or your access token

   ```
   $headers[] = 'Authorization: ACCESS_TOKEN';
   $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   ```
4. Executing the command and storing the result

   `$result = curl_exec($ch);`